# Using React Query and Flask to post and fetch

Tags: reactjs, flask, fetch-api, react-query

I am trying to post some data from some input fields, send it to my Flask backend, and then have some new data returned to me.

Currently I do this with the regular `fetch` option, but I thought I might try simplifying my code a bit. However, I might just be stupid, or haven't found it, but I can't seem to figure out the way to do it with e.g. React Query (there are options like SWR as well I guess).

Right now my `fetch` function, that is called on a submit button, looks like:

```
const MyApp = () => {

    const returnObjects = {
        returnData1: [],
        returnData2: [],
        returnData3: [],
    };

    const [data, setData] = useState(returnObjects);
    const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);

    function fetchData(e?: any) {
        e?.preventDefault();
        setLoadingState(true);
        fetch(`/api`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
               input1: inputOne
               input2: inputTwo,
           }),
        })
        .then(async (response) => {
            const json = await response.json();
            setData({
                returnData1: json.returnData1,
                returnData2: json.returnData2,
                returnData3: json.returnData3,
            });
            setLoadingState(false);
        });
    }

    const [inputOne, setInputOne] = useState(null);
    const [inputTwo, setInputTwo] = useState(null);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={fetchData}>
            <input type="number" value={inputOne} onChange={(e) => setInputOne(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="number" value={inputTwo} onChange={(e) => setInputTwo(e.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit">Fetch data</button>
        </form>

        <div>
            <p>{data.returnData1}</p>
            <p>{data.returnData2}</p>
            <p>{data.returnData3}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyApp;
```

So basically I post the data from my input fields, which is then given to the Flask backend, which does some calculations, and return the return data objects.

Again, can this be achieved with React Query as well, or...?

I've seen people using `mutation` and stuff, but then suddenly I don't think the code is that much cleaner to be honest. It's not like I need to store the data given as input at all. I just need some output from the backend depending on the input variables whenever I click the submit button.

Comment: _"can this be achieved with React Query"_... yes ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -4, accepted):

See the other answer, using a mutation is the correct way.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I will update the answer, thanks! i'm new to this

Comment: sorry, this is the wrong answer. using enabled + refetch is an escape hatch that tries to bypass what react-query is trying to do. It shouldn't be the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely looking for a mutation: If you have a POST request that creates something on the backend, that's not a query but a mutation.

If the mutation returns data and you also have a query that fetches that data, you can use [updates from mutation responses](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses) to update that data instead of refetching it.